# Create filename based on file output in shell

Tags: linux, bash

I'm looking to create files with names based on the command output of the previous command i.e. if i run

```
find . -name *.mp4 | wc -l > filename
```

So that the output of the amount of files of that type is the filename of the created file.

Comment: I think you'll probably need to use `mktemp` and then rename once you've parsed the output.

Comment: Hard to understand exactly what you need, but why not `n=$(ls -1 *.mp4 | wc -l); touch "$n-mp4"`?  (or `...; echo "$n" > "$n-mp4"`)

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco i think the mv command suggested by alexbclay did the rename you mentioned and changed its name based on the tail of the file contents.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin not sure if you got my question but the ls command didn't work for me as it didn't find any files with an extension of mp4 (not sure if it's distro related or not)

Comment: @John13 -- if your files reside in subdirectories, then `ls` will not work. (not without adjusting `globstar` in bash, etc..) and `find` is the proper tool. Which you can change to `n=$(find . -type f -name *.mp4 | wc -l); echo "$n" > "$n-mp4"; unset n`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks, they do reside in sub directories and the solution suggested now will work although i liked the one already given since it's simpler and less hassle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that renames the file after it has been created:

```
find . -name *.mp4 | wc -l > filename && mv filename `tail -n 1 filename`
```

---

What is happening in this one-liner:

`find . -name *mp4 | wc -l > filename` : Finds files with mp4 suffix and then counts how many were found and redirects the output to a file named `filename`

`tail -n 1 filename`: Outputs the very last line in the file named `filename`.  If you put backticks around it (`` `tail -n 1 filename` ``) then that statement is executed and replaced by the text it returns.

`` mv filename `tail -n 1 filename` ``: Renames the original file named `filename` to the executed statement above.

When you combine these with `&&`, the second statement only runs if the first was successful.

Comment: Awesome that worked, now i'm trying to understand why it works :)

Comment: Figured it out!
the and operand just adds another command to run instead of the output and move is used to rename the file from its contents using the evaluation of the tail command's output of the file contents, very clever actually and i really learned a lot of shell here, although i found many people saying $() should be used instead of backticks for eval

Comment: Thanks for the answer and clarification @alexbclay

Comment: If you already have a file named `filename`, it's in trouble. That's why I mentioned `mktemp`.